# SPARQL select remaining triples

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have an RDF graph with data in it that's described using different ontologies (think VCARD and FOAF).

Now to make my queries simpler I would like to construct a new graph in which I map one ontology onto the other so the data is described in one single ontology.

I have the mapping part figured out, but what I'm looking for is a way to select the 'remaining triples', i.e., the ones that are already in the correct ontology
(since these should be unchanged after the mapping).

I figure there should be a way to do this through negation, but I can't seem to figure it out.

For instance, let's say I have the following RDF graph:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@base <http://example.org/>

<somePerson>
    a foaf:Person .
<someOtherPerson>
    a vcard:Individual .
# [Some more triples]
```

And I want to map it to:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@base <http://example.org/>

<somePerson>
    a foaf:Person .
<someOtherPerson>
    a foaf:Person.
# [Some more triples]
```

to describe the data without using VCARD.

The mapping from the first to the second is simple enough, but I'm looking for a simple way to leave the other triples untouched. (Basically copy them to the output).

Comment: I do not fully understand but `FILTER NOT EXISTS` (or use `MINUS`) with the same pattern that you use for the mapping and this put into a CONSTRUCT query (or INSERT could work. Clearly, it would be easier with a minimal example + a mapping query + the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added an example for clarity.
In the meantime I found a way to achieve this, but it's quit cumbersome:

1. I make my query for the triples I want to translate.
2. I make a second query for general `?x ?y ?z .` and use a `FILTER NOT EXISTS` for every statement I use in the first query.
3. I take the union of both.

Comment: yeah, that's exacty what I meant with my comment. Repeat yourself with the mapping part but put it into the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` - that's the common way

Comment: Okay, well I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution, but if it works it works.
I'll add an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @UninformedUser suggested, this query structure will do the trick.

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#>
CONSTRUCT {
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person .
    ?x ?y ?z .
}
WHERE {
    {
        {
            ?x ?y ?z .
        }
        FILTER NOT EXISTS
        {
            ?x rdf:type vcard:Individual .
        }
    }
    UNION
    {
        ?name rdf:type vcard:Individual .
    }
}
```

To go from here:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@base <http://example.org/>

<somePerson>
    a foaf:Person .
<someOtherPerson>
    a vcard:Individual .
[Some more triples]
```

to here:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@base <http://example.org/>

<somePerson>
    a foaf:Person .
<someOtherPerson>
    a foaf:Person.
[Some more triples]
```